# Matching user name to user in table

Tags: filemaker

I need to get the currently logged in user's account name and match it to a user in my user's table. Then I want to get that user's associated Team ID.

More technically, I have a table of users, each with a `__pkUserID` field that corresponds to their Account Name that I created in the File > Manage > Security pane. Each user also has an `__fkTeamID`. When a user creates a new record I would like to set the `__fkTeamID` to the same `__fkTeamID` as the currently logged in user.

What's the best way to accomplish this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an utility table with one record only. Make a global field there to hold the current user ID.
Set this ID field in the startup script using Get(AccountName). You could use a global variable, but if you want to drive a relationship based on the current user later, you’ll need a global field.

Make another global field (or variable) to hold the team ID. Set this also in the startup script, grab it from the users table matched on the logged in user.
Set up an auto enter calculation from this field in the team ID fields in the tables where you need it.

Comment: How would I match the UserID to the Users table?

Comment: Simplest FileMaker way is to create a relationship between the global user ID and the pk field in the users table. If you know SQL you could just grab the matched team ID with the ExecuteSQL function.

Comment: I don't know SQL unfortunately. Here are some screenshots of what I have so far: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ivw8hungg4iyfx2/AACfuUv42NCB8IDzR1GpnP4la?dl=0

Comment: Utility table looks good,except CurrentUserID should not have an auto enter. get(Accountname) is put into this field by startup script. Utility table has only one record, always. Make a relationship from the utility CurrentUserID to UserID in the users table. Use that relationship in the calc for CurrentTeamID.

Answer (score 0):

Careful with account names, particularly when using Active Directory and external authentication. It's legal to login as...

accountname
accountname@domain
donain\accountname

... and the get( accountname ) function will return whatever string was authenticated.

Solve this by parsing out the name from the string returned from Get( accountname ) and use this to find the user record, and hence the team id.

I've made a custom function to do the parsing to make it easier to update the parsing algorithm as new variations become apparent.